# PHP only leave text in between particular characters

Tags: php, regex

I have many strings that look like this:

```
[additional-text Sample text...]
```

There is always an opening bracket + additional-text + single space and a closing bracket in the end and I need to remove all of them, so that the final string would look like this:

```
Sample text...
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this o get all matches within a text block:

```
preg_match_all("/\[additional-text (.*?)\]/",$text,$matches);
```

all your texts will be in $matches[1]. So that will be:

```
$text = "[additional-text Sample text...]dsfg fgfd[additional-text Sample text2...] foo bar adfd as ff";
preg_match_all("/\[additional-text (.*?)\]/",$str,$matches);
var_export($matches[1]);
```

Comment: Very elegant and prefered solution!

Answer (score 1):

Get the substring you want to keep as a captured group:

```
^\[\S+\s([^]]+)\]$
```

Now in the replacement, use the only captured group, `\1`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ8mV5/2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$re = '/\[\S+\s|\]/'; 
$str = "[additional-text Sample text...]"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);
//=> Sample text...
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bE7nF8/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use `substr` to remove the first 17 characters. Use regex to remove the last two:

```
$val = '[additional-text Sample text...]';
$text = preg_replace('#\]$#', '', substr($val, 17));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this

```
$a = '[additional-text Sample text...]';
$a= ltrim($a,"[additional-text ");
echo $a= rtrim($a,"]");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in regex, use [**`substr`**](http://php.net/manual/de/function.substr.php):

```
$s = "[additional-text Sample text...]";
echo substr($s, 17, strlen($s)-18);
```

Where `17` is the length of `[additional-text`  and `18` is the same + 1 for the last `]`.

See [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/VTKIFd)

A regex solution is also basic:

```
^\[additional-text (.*)]$
```

or - if there can be no `]` before the end:

```
^\[additional-text ([^]]*)]$
```

And replace with `$1` backreference. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD1uK7/2), and here is a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/uGVDgs):

```
$result = preg_replace('~^\[additional-text (.*)]$~', "$1", "[additional-text Sample text...]");
echo $result;
```

*Pattern details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\[` - a literal `[`
- `additional-text`  - literal text
- `(.*)` - zero or more characters other than a newline as many as possible up to
- `]$` - a `]` at the end of the string.

Comment: Please check if I have not missed anything and if everything is clear. In case you need more help, do not hesitate to drop a comment here.